# Phusion Passenger: Cannot create a subdirectory inside instance registry directory /tmp

Tags: 20.04, permissions, nginx

I'm currently deployed a Rails 6 application to an EC2 instance on Ubuntu 20.04. I deployed the Rails application using [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/deploy_updates/) and Nginx. I get the following error when I try to access the ec2 instance.

> Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered
> the following error during startup: Cannot create a subdirectory
> inside instance registry directory /tmp: No such file or directory
> (errno=2) (-1: Unknown error)

It seems is unable to write to `/tmp` file. I tried changing the permissions of the `/tmp` directory but this doesn't seem to be working. The current permissions is as followed.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxx:/var/www/tyrion$ ls -l
total 72
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1739 Jan 18 17:41 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 5779 Jan 18 17:41 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   31 Jan 18 17:41 PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  121 Jan 18 17:41 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  227 Jan 18 17:41 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 16 20:43 app
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:42 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  130 Jan 18 17:41 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 db
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 15 21:30 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 public
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 storage
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 18:28 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 18 17:41 vendor
```

Noticed that the permissions of `tmp` allow it `w` access to the directory. This is weird since in the configuration for Phusion [Passenger according to the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_instance_registry_dir) `passenger_instance_registry_dir` defaults to `/tmp`. Thus, not needing to declare `passenger_instance_registry_dir /tmp`, I even try with adding this line in the configuration but didn't have success.

Here is my passenger config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/tyrion/public;

        server_name _;

        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/wrappers/ruby; 
}
```

When I run `sudo passenger-status` I also get the following outcome.

> ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure
> that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:
>
> 1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
>    passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger
>    Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so,
>    please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to
>    that directory and run passenger-status again.
> 2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory
>    using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
>    passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger
>    Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.

This confuses me since `/tmp` is the default registry dir. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For `nginx` you can add the configuration in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf`

```
passenger_instance_registry_dir /tmp;
```